# convert backslash to dict python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this string and I want to convert it to a dictionary.

```
resu = {
    "list_file":"{

    \"iross\": [
        \"artt\",
        \"artction\",
        \"artiong\",
        \"artiype\",
        \"coon\",
        \"colleong\",
        \"collype\",
        \"genre\",
        \"genst\",
        \"genction\",
        \"rle\",
        \"sog\",
        \"storont\",
        \"mepe\",
    ],
    \"mch\": [\"mach\", \"coltch\", \"stch\"],
    \"popularity\": [\"album_poe\", \"song_populanre\"]
}"}
```

Comment: The value of `resu` that you provided is not valid python. Should the whole thing be a string maybe?

Comment: Please share what the expected result is and what have you tried so far. Amending the question with this info will increase the chance of getting good answers.

Comment: It looks like a json string. If it's a valid json, you could do `json.loads(resu['list_file'])`

Answer (score 0):

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) was born for this:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

resu = { "list_file":"{\"iross\": [\"artt\",\"artction\",\"artiong\",\"artiype\",\"coon\",\"colleong\",\"collype\",\"genre\",\"genst\",\"genction\",\"rle\",\"sog\",\"storont\",\"mepe\",],\"mch\": [\"mach\", \"coltch\", \"stch\"],\"popularity\": [\"album_poe\",\"song_populanre\"]}"}

new_dict = literal_eval(resu['list_file'])
```